# What is a debug working set (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, working-set

I'm using Eclipse IDE and notice an option in the Debug perspective in the Breakpoints view that allows me to chose/create a working set. I've found all kinds of help online that tells me how to make a working set or choose a working set, but nothing that explains what a working set is or why I'd want to use one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A working set is a subset of other objects.  You can create a breakpoint working set that contains only some of your breakpoints, or a project working set that contains only part of your project, and so on.  You would use working sets to let you easily switch back and forth between different parts of a project or workspace.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you will need to set the grouping to be by "Breakpoint Working Set" to be able to toggle each working set's breakpoints easily. Before, I tried to select the working set and didn't notice any particular changes.